# Does my gofmt work wrongly or I don't understand something?

Tags: go, gofmt

I suppose that my `gofmt` works not how it's supposed to, am I right ?

Original file:

```
package main


import "fmt"


func main() {
    fmt.Printf("hello, world\n")
}
```

Then I did:

```
gofmt -r 'h -> H' -w "hello.go"
```

Content of the file after:

```
package H


import "fmt"


func H() {
 H
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Presumably `gofmt` works as its authors intended, which might be different from what you expected.
The [documentation](https://golang.org/cmd/gofmt/) says:

> Both pattern and replacement must be valid Go expressions. In the pattern, single-character lowercase identifiers serve as wildcards matching arbitrary sub-expressions; those expressions will be substituted for the same identifiers in the replacement.

As you have only a single lowercase letter in the pattern, *it matches all sub-expressions*. And then replaces them with `H`. Let's take your example further, consider this:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func compare(a, b int) {
    if a + b < a * b {
        fmt.Printf("hello, world\n")
    }
}
```

After the same `gofmt` command the above code becomes:

```
package H

import "fmt"

func H(H, H H) {
    if H+H < H*H {
        H
    }
}
```

If this is not what you want, then you should use a more specific pattern expression.